# how to translate the GPS coordinates in the form (degrees, minutes, seconds) C #?

Tags: c#

```
PropertyItem GpsAltitudeProperty = photo.GetPropertyItem(0x0004);
string GpsAltitude = BitConverter.ToString(GpsAltitudeProperty.Value);

textBox7.Text = GpsAltitude.ToString();
```

displays:

> 21-00-00-00-01-00-00-00-24-00-00-00-01-00-00-00-50-34-00-00-E8-03-00-00

You need to get the coordinates of the form:(33 degrees 36 minutes 13.39 seconds)
21 is 33 in decimal system is 36 to 24 in the decimal system as well as the second recorded in 16-bit hexadecimal system do not understand. And how to get in the normal way.: 33 degrees 36 minutes 13.39 seconds)
21 is 33 in decimal system is 36 to 24 in the decimal system as well as the second recorded in 16-bit hexadecimal system do not understand.

Comment: And you want us to do your work? This is not a "do my coding" forum. If you have code that does not work - we help. Doing your work - no. And it is not afternoon where I am,

Comment: you need to split your data, which part is degree, which part is minutes ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need read about [BitConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter(v=vs.110).aspx).[ToInt32](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.toint32(v=vs.110).aspx).

You can write something like this:

```
byte[] Value = new byte[] { 0x21, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x24, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x50, 0x34, 0x00, 0x00, 0xE8, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00 };
int deg = BitConverter.ToInt32(Value, 0);    // convert first 4 bytes to int
int min = BitConverter.ToInt32(Value, 8);    // convert bytes  8 - 11 to int
int ss = BitConverter.ToInt32(Value, 16);    // convert bytes 16 - 19 to int

double sec = ss / 1000 + Math.Round((ss % 1000) / 1000.0, 2);

string output = string.Format(@"{0} degrees {1} minutes {2} seconds", deg, min, sec);
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

Output:

```
33 degrees 36 minutes 13.39 seconds
```